# Silverlight 4 with SQLite or alternative

Tags: database, sqlite, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I am making a Silverlight app and what I considered something straight-forward really isn't.

I am in need to create a application where a local database is stored on the web server where the Silverlight application can connect to and whenever a user goes on the application will allow sql queries to be carried out. Main use is Registration, login and event registration.

I have tried the Community SQLite: http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

But had trouble getting it to work with Silverlight, my guess is due to poor documentation. I already have made a project containing a lot of work so I just want to implement my SQLite code into that.

Can anyone help

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Silverlight application to have a LOCAL storage database, [check out Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/).

If you want your Silverlight application to query a centralized, server-side database, then you need to expose your database via WCF. [RIA services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/) is probably the easiest implementation.

Comment: Well I don't want each user who goes on the page to have their own database, I just want one database set for the silverlight application to use, storing data that all users will use. So Sterling would be the best bet?

Comment: Nope, the other way around. You want a server side database like SQL Server, and then you want to expose this database via service calls.

Comment: I was hoping to have something like SQLite but I guess I will muck about with SQL Server. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can still use SQLite (or any other database for that matter), but the idea is the same. You must expose the data via service calls to your Silverlight client.